# Update table by selecting values from multiple tables sql

Tags: sql

I am updating the table with values from multiple tables.

```
UPDATE pv SET
            pv.[TotalDInTCG] = Dr.TCGDCnt
            ,pv.[AvgHbA1cImprovement] = hsd.AvgHbA1cCnt
            ,pv.[TotalCHDInTCG] = cpc.CHdCnt
            ,pv.[TotalCHDNTCG] = cpd1.CHdWithCholBPCnt
            ,pv.[PercentageOfCHDWithBPChol] = icp.CHFElligPopul
            ,pv.[TotalCOPDInTCG] = copd.TcgCOPDcount
            ,pv.[TotalCOPDMRCPOxySatuLevel] = copdmrc.TotalCOLevel
            ,pv.[PercentOferTCG] = copdOxSatu.oxySatligPopu
        FROM #tmpeTabel AS pv
            INNER JOIN #DRegistered AS Dr
            ON  Dr.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
                AND Dr.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
                AND Dr.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
            INNER JOIN #HbA1cScoreDetails AS hsd
            ON  hsd.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
                AND hsd.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
                AND hsd.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
            INNER JOIN #CHDCount as cpc
            ON  cpc.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
                AND cpc.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
                AND cpc.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
            INNER JOIN #CHDBPCholPatientsDetails as cpd1
            ON  cpd1.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
                AND cpd1.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
                AND cpd1.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
            INNER JOIN #ImprovementCHFPerPractice as icp
            ON  icp.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
                AND icp.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
                AND icp.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
            INNER JOIN #COPDCount as copd
            ON  copd.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
                AND copd.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
                AND copd.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
            INNER JOIN #COPDDetailsMRCOxygenSatuLevel as copdmrc
            ON  copdmrc.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
                AND copdmrc.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
                AND copdmrc.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
            INNER JOIN #ImprovPerElligPopula as copdOxSatu
            ON  copdOxSatu.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
                AND copdOxSatu.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
                AND copdOxSatu.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
```

The issue here is , some tables have many rows and some have less rows. But i am getting the less rows for all every table after update

Should i use update separably for each select table..

Comment: That's normal you use INNER JOIN everywhere...Have you try with LEFT OUTER JOIN ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the columns you are updating in `pv` are all nullable this should ensure you capture all the relevant data:

```
UPDATE pv SET
        pv.[TotalDInTCG] = Dr.TCGDCnt
        ,pv.[AvgHbA1cImprovement] = hsd.AvgHbA1cCnt
        ,pv.[TotalCHDInTCG] = cpc.CHdCnt
        ,pv.[TotalCHDNTCG] = cpd1.CHdWithCholBPCnt
        ,pv.[PercentageOfCHDWithBPChol] = icp.CHFElligPopul
        ,pv.[TotalCOPDInTCG] = copd.TcgCOPDcount
        ,pv.[TotalCOPDMRCPOxySatuLevel] = copdmrc.TotalCOLevel
        ,pv.[PercentOferTCG] = copdOxSatu.oxySatligPopu
    FROM #tmpeTabel AS pv
        LEFT JOIN #DRegistered AS Dr
        ON  Dr.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
            AND Dr.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
            AND Dr.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
        LEFT JOIN #HbA1cScoreDetails AS hsd
        ON  hsd.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
            AND hsd.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
            AND hsd.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
        LEFT JOIN #CHDCount as cpc
        ON  cpc.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
            AND cpc.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
            AND cpc.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
        LEFT JOIN #CHDBPCholPatientsDetails as cpd1
        ON  cpd1.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
            AND cpd1.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
            AND cpd1.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
        LEFT JOIN #ImprovementCHFPerPractice as icp
        ON  icp.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
            AND icp.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
            AND icp.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
        LEFT JOIN #COPDCount as copd
        ON  copd.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
            AND copd.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
            AND copd.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
        LEFT JOIN #COPDDetailsMRCOxygenSatuLevel as copdmrc
        ON  copdmrc.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
            AND copdmrc.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
            AND copdmrc.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
        LEFT JOIN #ImprovPerElligPopula as copdOxSatu
        ON  copdOxSatu.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
            AND copdOxSatu.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
            AND copdOxSatu.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN You can update the value even if it is not with match with some tables.

USE ISNULL function to avoid the updating null values in the PV

```
UPDATE pv SET
                pv.[TotalDInTCG] = Dr.TCGDCnt
                ,pv.[AvgHbA1cImprovement] = hsd.AvgHbA1cCnt
                ,pv.[TotalCHDInTCG] = cpc.CHdCnt
                ,pv.[TotalCHDNTCG] = cpd1.CHdWithCholBPCnt
                ,pv.[PercentageOfCHDWithBPChol] = icp.CHFElligPopul
                ,pv.[TotalCOPDInTCG] = copd.TcgCOPDcount
                ,pv.[TotalCOPDMRCPOxySatuLevel] = copdmrc.TotalCOLevel
                ,pv.[PercentOferTCG] = copdOxSatu.oxySatligPopu
            FROM #tmpeTabel AS pv
                LEFT JOIN #DRegistered AS Dr
                ON  Dr.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
                    AND Dr.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
                    AND Dr.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
                LEFT JOIN #HbA1cScoreDetails AS hsd
                ON  hsd.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
                    AND hsd.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
                    AND hsd.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
                LEFT JOIN #CHDCount as cpc
                ON  cpc.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
                    AND cpc.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
                    AND cpc.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
                LEFT JOIN #CHDBPCholPatientsDetails as cpd1
                ON  cpd1.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
                    AND cpd1.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
                    AND cpd1.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
                LEFT JOIN #ImprovementCHFPerPractice as icp
                ON  icp.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
                    AND icp.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
                    AND icp.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
                LEFT JOIN #COPDCount as copd
                ON  copd.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
                    AND copd.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
                    AND copd.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
                LEFT JOIN #COPDDetailsMRCOxygenSatuLevel as copdmrc
                ON  copdmrc.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
                    AND copdmrc.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
                    AND copdmrc.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
                LEFT JOIN #ImprovPerElligPopula as copdOxSatu
                ON  copdOxSatu.SK_ServiceProviderID = pv.SK_ServiceProviderID
                    AND copdOxSatu.Years = pv.[ReportYear]
                    AND copdOxSatu.Months = pv.[ReportMonth]
```

Answer (score 0):

Left outer join worked.. The main issue was due to normal behavior of INNER JOIN